# Keyboard works sometimes, fails mostly

Tags: wireless-keyboard

I have a wireless keyboard (not bluetooth), and sometimes it works, sometimes it just doesn't, and sometimes it give me the "USB device not recognized" error.

What could be wrong with the wireless receiver? I mean, it's not a total failure, so maybe there is something to do about it.

I can't buy a new receiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all other usb devices work, here are three things to try.

- Test on another usb port
- Make sure that the keyboard is close enough to the receiver (possibly move the receiver to one of the front usb ports?)
- Replace the batterys in the keyboard

If neither of those fix the problem i would cut your losses and replace the keyboard